# Is this possible with decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm exploring my way through the language while building real applications. Right now I'm trying to build an event-based app, and was thinking about using decorators as a way to add functions as listeners:

```
@onEvent(eventSpecificArgument)
def foo():
    print('foo')
```

In the above example, I have added the function foo as a listener for the event, and have passed an argument that will be used by the decorator.

Is this a possible (and smart enough) solution for what I want? And if it is, how could/should I implement it?

Comment: Do you like metaprogramming? I love this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI

Comment: Not only is it possible and perfectly reasonable, depending on which GUI or networking or other event-based framework you're using, it may already exist (or something close enough for you to build this trivially might already exist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, decorators are *just callables*. Decorator notation is just syntactic sugar, your example translates to:

```
def foo():
    print('foo')
foo = onEvent(eventSpecificArgument)(foo)
```

so your `onEvent()` callable needs to return something that can be called; that 'something' will be passed in `foo`.

Whatever you do in `onEvent` and in the 'something' it returned is up to you.

Something like the following would work:

```
registry = {}

def onEvent(eventname):
    def eventdecorator(func):
        registry.setdefault(eventname, []).append(func)
        return func
    return eventdecorator
```

This just adds `func` to the registry for a given eventname and returns the function unchanged.

Later on, when you then need to handle the event, you just look up the event handlers for that event with:

```
for func in registry.get(eventname, ()):
    func()
```

Comment: Might want to add `functools.wraps` around `eventdecorator` and use a `defaultdict` instead of `dict.setdefault`.

Comment: I'm not wrapping the function here; so `functools.wraps` makes no sense.